# Unknown Error, Ben Awad's "Fullstack React GraphQL TypeScript Tutorial"

Tags: typescript

I am working in the project from Ben Awad's "Fullstack React GraphQL TypeScript Tutorial".

In the index.ts, the majority of my code in highlighted red.

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItUNp.jpg)

I have the following error when I hover over the code

```
Argument of type '{ schema: GraphQLSchema; context: ({ req, res }: ExpressContext) => 
MyContext; plugins: any[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 
'Config<ExpressContext>'.
Type '{ schema: GraphQLSchema; context: ({ req, res }: ExpressContext) => MyContext; 
plugins: any[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 
'Config<ExpressContext>': logger, debug, cache, formatError, and 6 more.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is complaining because it's expecting type `Config<ExpressContext>`, and instead it's receiving type `{ schema: GraphQLSchema; context: ({ req, res }: ExpressContext) =>  MyContext; plugins: any[]; }`.

Assuming you don't care about the missing properties, you could cast it to `Config<ExpressContext>`:

`{ schema: GraphQLSchema; context: ({ req, res }: ExpressContext) =>  MyContext; plugins: any[]; } as Config<ExpressContext>`.